# Can't switch to fullscreen at Kali Linux

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux, fullscreen

I can't go to fullscreen at Kali Linux after I log in. Before the login VirtualBox is automatically resizing. At the first times it was working. I don't know why it got broken. I installed Guest Additions with 2 diffrent ways. Also the "Auto-resize guest" option is ticked. kali or root account does not make any difference. I am using Kali Linux 2020.2a with latest VirtualBox and latest extension pack.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue guest additions must match with latest VirtualBox version.
Mines guest additions was 6.1.6
And VirtualBox 6.1.12
If you are having the same issue then make sure you have got the latest VirtualBox, VirtualBox extension pack and guest additions. After that tick the option Auto-resize Guest Display which is listed at the view options